# Sql Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have sql query:

```
SELECT leads.lead_id,
       attributes.code     AS attributeCode,
       leads_notes.content AS noteContent,
       leads_notes.task_type_id,
       task_types.type_name
FROM   leads,
       leads_notes
       INNER JOIN task_types
               ON task_types.task_type_id = leads_notes.task_type_id
       INNER JOIN leads_attributes
               ON leads_attributes.lead_id = leads.lead_id
       INNER JOIN attributes
               ON attributes.attribute_id = leads_attributes.attribute_id
       INNER JOIN leads_notes
               ON leads_notes.lead_id = leads.lead_id
WHERE  ( leads.ambassador = 1
          OR leads.rents_bike = 1 )
       AND ( leads.city <> '' )
       AND ( leads.address <> ''
              OR leads.address2 <> '' )
       AND ( leads.country_id <> '' )
       AND ( leads_attributes.attribute_id IN ( $attributes_id ) )
       AND ( leads.lead_id = $lead_id )
```

But I get error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:
>   'leads_notes''

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Don't mix comma separated tables and explicit joins, it's just too confusing. (Where's that join condition?)

Comment: `leads_notes` is hanging in there without any join condition. Is that really needed because you have joined the same table at the end. That explains the error as well

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In your case you also had `lead_notes` twice in the `FROM` clause.  It is easier to write and read the query if you use table aliases:

```
SELECT  l.lead_id, a.code as attributeCode, ln.content as noteContent, ln.task_type_id, tt.type_name 
FROM leads l JOIN
     leads_notes ln
     ON ln.lead_id = l.lead_id JOIN 
     task_types tt
     ON tt.task_type_id = ln.task_type_id JOIN
     leads_attributes la
     ON  la.lead_id = l.lead_id JOIN
     attributes a
     ON a.attribute_id = la.attribute_id
WHERE (l.ambassador=1  OR l.rents_bike=1)  AND
      (l.city <> '') AND
      (l.address <>'' OR l.address2 <>'') AND 
      (l.country_id <> '')  AND
      (la.attribute_id IN ($attributes_id)) AND
      (l.lead_id = $lead_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have add `leads_notes` table double: one in after `leads` table and another in `inner join`, so remove one solve your problem like following

```
SELECT leads.lead_id,
       attributes.code     AS attributeCode,
       leads_notes.content AS noteContent,
       leads_notes.task_type_id,
       task_types.type_name
FROM   leads
       INNER JOIN task_types
               ON task_types.task_type_id = leads_notes.task_type_id
       INNER JOIN leads_attributes
               ON leads_attributes.lead_id = leads.lead_id
       INNER JOIN attributes
               ON attributes.attribute_id = leads_attributes.attribute_id
       INNER JOIN leads_notes
               ON leads_notes.lead_id = leads.lead_id
WHERE  ( leads.ambassador = 1
          OR leads.rents_bike = 1 )
       AND ( leads.city <> '' )
       AND ( leads.address <> ''
              OR leads.address2 <> '' )
       AND ( leads.country_id <> '' )
       AND ( leads_attributes.attribute_id IN ( $attributes_id ) )
       AND ( leads.lead_id = $lead_id )
```

Comment: I got errror: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'leads_notes.task_type_id' in 'on clause''

Comment: what is your column of `leads_notes` table?

Comment: there is  task_type_id column